# How to create groups based on conditions

Tags: r

I have this kind of data:

```
set.seed(12345)

df <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A"),26), size=c(rep(1000,5),rep(0,3),rep(1000,7),rep(0,3),rep(1000,5),rep(0,3)),
             int=c(rnorm(3,5,1),rep(0,5),rnorm(3,5,1),rep(0,7),rnorm(3,5,1),rep(0,5)),
             out=c(rep(0,5),rnorm(3,5,1),rep(0,7),rnorm(3,5,1),rep(0,5),rnorm(3,5,1)))
```

Here is desired output:

```
   group size      int      out  id  id2
1      A 1000 5.585529 0.000000   1    1
2      A 1000 5.709466 0.000000   1    1
3      A 1000 4.890697 0.000000   1    1
4      A 1000 0.000000 0.000000   1    1
5      A 1000 0.000000 0.000000   1    1
6      A    0 0.000000 4.080678   1    1
7      A    0 0.000000 4.883752   NA   1
8      A    0 0.000000 6.817312   NA   1
9      A 1000 4.546503 0.000000   2    2
10     A 1000 5.605887 0.000000   2    2
11     A 1000 3.182044 0.000000   2    2
12     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000   2    2
13     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000   2    2
14     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000   2    2
15     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000   2    2
16     A    0 0.000000 5.370628   2    2
17     A    0 0.000000 5.520216   NA   2
18     A    0 0.000000 4.249468   NA   2
19     A 1000 5.630099 0.000000   3    3 
20     A 1000 4.723816 0.000000   3    3
21     A 1000 4.715840 0.000000   3    3
22     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000   3    3
23     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000   3    3
24     A    0 0.000000 5.816900   3    3
25     A    0 0.000000 4.113642   NA   3
26     A    0 0.000000 4.668422   NA   3
```

The new group `id` is created based on the data above. I believe `rle` function is the way to go, but I cannot figure it out to the end.

Comment: So what's the rule for creating `id`?

Comment: if you are observing (size!=0 & (int!=0 | int==0) & out==0)+1 start new group...

Comment: What about the `NA`'s though? Shouldn't those be group numbers too according to your rule?

Comment: there is also variable `size`...

Comment: You should describe in words what the rule is, edited into the question.

Comment: Thanks Frank, well, my wording could be imprecise (as I learned from the past) therefore I'm rather carefully designing the desired output, so far it always worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation on @ycw's answer:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, g := rleid( z <- out==0 | shift(out==0) )*NA^(!z) ]

    group size      int      out  g
 1:     A 1000 5.585529 0.000000  1
 2:     A 1000 5.709466 0.000000  1
 3:     A 1000 4.890697 0.000000  1
 4:     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000  1
 5:     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000  1
 6:     A    0 0.000000 4.080678  1
 7:     A    0 0.000000 4.883752 NA
 8:     A    0 0.000000 6.817312 NA
 9:     A 2000 4.546503 0.000000  3
10:     A 2000 5.605887 0.000000  3
11:     A 2000 3.182044 0.000000  3
12:     A 2000 0.000000 0.000000  3
13:     A 2000 0.000000 0.000000  3
14:     A 2000 0.000000 0.000000  3
15:     A 2000 0.000000 0.000000  3
16:     A    0 0.000000 5.370628  3
17:     A    0 0.000000 5.520216 NA
18:     A    0 0.000000 4.249468 NA
19:     A 5000 5.630099 0.000000  5
20:     A 5000 4.723816 0.000000  5
21:     A 5000 4.715840 0.000000  5
22:     A 5000 0.000000 0.000000  5
23:     A 5000 0.000000 0.000000  5
24:     A    0 0.000000 5.816900  5
25:     A    0 0.000000 4.113642 NA
26:     A    0 0.000000 4.668422 NA
    group size      int      out  g
```

(@ycw suggested I make it a separate answer. Also, the `NA^x` trick is borrowed from @akrun.)

For the OP's group numbers, this extra step works:

```
df[, g := match(g, unique(na.omit(g)))]
```

For the extension the OP added ("id2"):

```
w = df[.(unique(na.omit(g))), on=.(g), which=TRUE, mult="first"]
df[, g2 := cumsum(.I %in% w)]
```

So in the end we have...

```
    group size      int      out  g g2
 1:     A 1000 5.585529 0.000000  1  1
 2:     A 1000 5.709466 0.000000  1  1
 3:     A 1000 4.890697 0.000000  1  1
 4:     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000  1  1
 5:     A 1000 0.000000 0.000000  1  1
 6:     A    0 0.000000 4.080678  1  1
 7:     A    0 0.000000 4.883752 NA  1
 8:     A    0 0.000000 6.817312 NA  1
 9:     A 2000 4.546503 0.000000  2  2
10:     A 2000 5.605887 0.000000  2  2
11:     A 2000 3.182044 0.000000  2  2
12:     A 2000 0.000000 0.000000  2  2
13:     A 2000 0.000000 0.000000  2  2
14:     A 2000 0.000000 0.000000  2  2
15:     A 2000 0.000000 0.000000  2  2
16:     A    0 0.000000 5.370628  2  2
17:     A    0 0.000000 5.520216 NA  2
18:     A    0 0.000000 4.249468 NA  2
19:     A 5000 5.630099 0.000000  3  3
20:     A 5000 4.723816 0.000000  3  3
21:     A 5000 4.715840 0.000000  3  3
22:     A 5000 0.000000 0.000000  3  3
23:     A 5000 0.000000 0.000000  3  3
24:     A    0 0.000000 5.816900  3  3
25:     A    0 0.000000 4.113642 NA  3
26:     A    0 0.000000 4.668422 NA  3
    group size      int      out  g g2
```

For base R analogues, there is an SO Q&A on how to make `rleid` without data.table; `shift` can be constructed manually (it's just a lag operator); and there are other ways to find `w` (maybe `tapply`?).

Comment: great thanks! Would you be so kind and provide solution for the `id2`? Hopefully base r. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fyi, as ycw noted, it's poor etiquette here (or at least an inconvenience) to substantially edit a question after an answer has been posted without first getting the answerer's go-ahead. (In this case, I mean ycw, since I posted after your edit anyways.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `dplyr` and the `rleid` function from the `data.table` package. `dt2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(non_zero = ifelse(size != 0, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(runID = rleid(non_zero)) %>%
  mutate(runID = ifelse(runID %% 2 != 0, (runID + 1)/2, runID/2)) %>%
  group_by(runID) %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(row_number() %in% n():(n() - 1), NA, runID)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(group, size, int, out, id, id2 = runID)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works on test data but not on real data. I have now amended the sample data, your solution seems to rely purely on `size` which in some cases is the same...

Comment: Hmm, no it works on the amended data...well I don't see other variables used in your solution that would be linked to the sample data...so I cannot use your solution to adapt to real case data...

Comment: @Maximilian It is probably a good idea you generated a test dataset that can represent your actual dataset. As you can see, my approach works both for the current and previous test dataset. There must be some key differences between your test and actual data.

Comment: yes I have tried of course to mirror the real data but it is not always easy to simplify...also I don't expect full solution always, I can adapt proposed solution, but this solution is too complicated for me :(

Comment: Similarly with a data.table, `df[, g := rleid(z <- out==0 | shift(out==0))*NA^(!z) ]` though the groups need to be releveled.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for sharing and it works great! I think it would be great if you can submit this approach as an answer.

Comment: I'm getting error: Error in `:=`(g, rleid(z <- out == 0 | shift(out == 0)) * NA^(!z)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: @Maximilian I think if you keep changing the testing data, it would confuse other readers. How about you start a new post with updated testing data? At least I think it is a good post with reproducible example and answers. keep changing it is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @Maximilian To use the `data.table`, you may need to use `setDT(df)` to convert the `df` to a data.table first.

Comment: I changed it only once, the `size` but now I added `id2` new column, that would be also solution...I can work with and I would adapt it myself further...

Comment: @Maximilian I have updated my answer to match your updated output. But you should know that this is tedious and time-consuming to make such changes. Next time please prepare your desired output carefully and don't change it once you post it.

Comment: ycw: thank you very much! I'm very sorry for changing the sample data. I have now upvoted your solution, thank you.